# Storing Excel/Word documents Windows Azure Blob Storage Files Corrupted

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, azure-storage

We've started using Azure blob storage api to store the uploaded blobs on our site, images have worked fine but when we upload a word/excel document and return the Url and try to download the file from that url and open it we get an error in Excel or Word saying:

"Excel cannot open the file "somefile.xlsx" because the format or file extension is not valid.  Verify that the file has not been corrupted and that the file extension matches the format of the file".

I know I must be missing something obvious but not sure what, below is the code we are using:

```
  CloudBlobContainer container = GetCloudBlobContainer();

  Guid guid = Guid.NewGuid();
  string storeFilename = String.Concat(mediaType.ToString(), "/", guid, "_", filename);

  var blob = container.GetBlobReference(storeFilename);
  blob.Properties.ContentType = contentType;
  blob.UploadFromStream(stream);

  return blob.Uri.AbsolutePath;
```

We return the Url and store that against the file that has been uploaded and use that as the link to download the file.

The file downloads fine, is the exact same size as the uploaded but won't open.

Any help would be greatly appreciated as it must be something so obvious but it eludes me I'm afraid.

Answer (score 0):

What code are you using to save the document to Azure?

What is the value of ContentType on Upload and download?

Are you UTF8 encoding the upload stream?

Take a look at [this upload example](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/davidlem/archive/2009/07/20/save-your-word-docs-to-windows-azure-blobs.aspx) that sets a ContentType and UTF8 encodes prior to uploading.